# Why can I not change the values in a subset of cells from a DataFrame column?

Tags: pandas, slice

I am indexing a **subset** of cells from a DataFrame column and attempting to assign a boolean `True` to said subset:

```
df['mycolumn'][df['myothercolumn'] == val][idx: idx + 25] = True
```

However, when I slice `df['mycolumn'][df['myothercolumn'] == val][idx: idx + 25]`, my the initial values are still found.  In other words **the changes were not applied!**

I'm about to rip my hair out.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: read this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy, your modifing a copy, use .loc or .ix, df.loc[boolean_on_rows,column_selector] = True

Comment: @Jeff, I'll definitely read it though, although that's quite an encyclopedia!  Thanks for the quick fix!

Comment: I had only meant to show the section 'returning a view versus a copy'. that should explain this question (of course I recommend reading the whole document too!)

Comment: @Jeff, Ah okay!  Thanks for the clarification.  I'm sure I'll end up reading the whole thing at some point ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.loc[df['myothercolumn']==val, some_column_name] = True
```

`some_column_name` should be the name of the column you want to add or change.